# Pass many optional parameters to route in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I need to built URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/param1/param2/param3/.../paramN
```

in a search page, user searchs by any possible options so making a URL like it in Laravel would be like this:

```
Route::get('{param1?}/{param2?}/{param3?}/.../{paramN?}', array( ... ) );
```

Is there any other way? Or maybe pass `/` as a part of parameter to have this:

```
low_range-1000/high_range-5000/weight-2/height-4/red/
```

so above line become just one parameter to route.

any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well, I found the solution. just to save others time.

```
Route::get('{param1}/{param2?}', array( ... ) )->where('param2', '.*');
```

this routes needs param1 as a required parameter, and param2 as an optional parameter which can contain any character includes `/`.

so I can pass `low_range-1000/high_range-5000/weight-2/height-4/red/` as param2.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar in my URLs, however I use commas to separate search parameters and `:` to separate the key:value

```
low-range:1000,high-range:5000,weight:2,height:4,color:red
```

Looks cleaner I think and you don't need to allow everything in your URLs or mess with allowing / in a parameter

P.S. having too many / in a URL is considered a bad practice for SEO purposes